# Align image in css

Tags: html, css

I want to align the images the following way.

I have one parent container div, inside that it has 3 children. 'Title text 1' div, image div and 'Title text 2' div.

One thing is that I don't want to crop the image. And I don't want the page to scroll.

```
 <div
    style={{
      height: "100vh",
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
      padding: "32px",
    }}
  >
    <div>Title Text 1</div>
    <div style={{ flex: "1" }}>
      <img
        style={{ width: "auto", height: "100%", objectFit: "contain" }}
        src="https://i.insider.com/59d1a7abd7605b4b008b4898?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp"
      />
    </div>
    <div>Title Text 2</div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Googled "align image in css". Second link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: yes, I have added the code above, Thats what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a little trick for the image and the parent div and everything will be fine.

- First add `position: relative` to the image parent's div
- Add the following code `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%); max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;` to the img tag for centering and still maintain the image ratio. Oh and remove all your code there first.